# TYPO3 8.7 - core extension form is setting fe_typo_user

Tags: forms, cookies, typo3, typo3-8.x

We are using the core extension "`form`" in TYPO3 8.7.30
On the frontend page containing the form a cookie "fe_typo_user" is set.

We don't use user registration or management to store, validate or finish fields.
Is this cookie necessary and how can I deactivate it?

I checked all other settings. All other pages (without form) are cookie free.
I want to avoid all cookies to comply with data protection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is necessary and there is no configuration option to disable this. It's a session cookie which is needed for the form's honeypot functionality to reduce spam.